# Julia: How to set the package Dev path?

Tags: julia

I often `]dev Pkg` but I want the `dev`ved packaged to be stored somewhere other than the default location for convenient access.

I don't want to change the path of the `]add Pkg`. This seems to be controlled by the environment parameter `DEPOT_PATH`.

Is there a way to change only the path for `dev Pkg`, i.e. the path in which the `dev` package is stored?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the environment variable `JULIA_PKG_DEVDIR` to change where development packages are installed. See the [develop docs](https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1/repl/#repl-develop) for more info.

As @crstnbr noted, an alternative is to use the `--local` option to the `pkg> dev` command to install a development version of the package in a `dev` directory within the current project. This could make sense if you're developing your own package `MyCode.jl` which relies on `Example.jl` and you need to make a hot fix to `Example.jl`. Then your Pkg REPL command would look like this:

```
(MyCode) pkg> dev --local Example
```

If you would like to make changes to a third-party package and submit those changes as a pull request on Github, there are a few more steps in the process. See [this Discourse thread](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/develop-a-local-version-of-a-registered-package-and-submit-changes-as-a-pull-request/24868/1) for more details on that process.

Comment: Maybe you should also mention the `--local` option which stores the package in a dev folder in the current project directory.

Answer (score 5):

Not quite what you're asking for but you can of course always `git clone` the package to a path of your choice and then `dev path/to/the/local/clone/of/the/pkg`.

You can even do this from within julia:

```
using Pkg
Pkg.GitTools.clone("<pkg url>", "<local path>")
Pkg.develop(PackageSpec(path="<local path>"))
```

Comment: In the newest version of Julia, the first argument has to be `::IO`:

  help?> Pkg.GitTools.clone
  No documentation found.

  Pkg.GitTools.clone is a Function.

  # 1 method for generic function "clone":
  [1] clone(io::IO, url, source_path; header, credentials, kwargs...) in Pkg.GitTools at /home/user/Software/julia-1.7.2/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Pkg/src/GitTools.jl:88